# Data between ContainerView and ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass data between my container view and my viewcontroller. Then, I click on the button the label text should be change. The button is in the container view and the label text in the viewcontroller. I tried some solutions here on Stack Overflow but nothing seems to working, or I'm doing it wrong maybe.

Can anyone help?

Gamecontroller.swift

```
@objc func buttonMove(_ sender:UIButton!) {

    print("Button tapped" + String(pointsGame))

    let buttonWidth = sender.frame.width;
    let buttonHeight = sender.frame.height;

    let viewWidth = sender.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = sender.superview!.bounds.height

    let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

    sender.center.x = xoffset + buttonWidth / 2
    sender.center.y = yoffset + buttonHeight / 2

    pointsGame = pointsGame + 1
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "game" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        vc.gpoints = pointsGame
    }
```

View controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var points: UILabel!
    var gpoints: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gpoints = 0
        points.text = String(gpoints)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try delegates.

Answer (score 2):

Gamecontroller.swift

```
////// declare object first
    var vc = ViewController()

@objc func buttonMove(_ sender:UIButton!) {

  print("Button tapped" + String(pointsGame))

  let buttonWidth = sender.frame.width;
  let buttonHeight = sender.frame.height;

  let viewWidth = sender.superview!.bounds.width
  let viewHeight = sender.superview!.bounds.height

  let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
  let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight

  let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
  let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))

  sender.center.x = xoffset + buttonWidth / 2
  sender.center.y = yoffset + buttonHeight / 2

  pointsGame = pointsGame + 1
  vc.refreshView((points : pointsGame)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "game" {
      vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
      vc.gpoints = pointsGame
}
```

View controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var points: UILabel!
    var gpoints: Int!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      gpoints = 0

  }
  func refreshView(points : Int! )
  {
      points.text = String(points)
  }
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't just paste the code. Explain what you have changed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hello @ozan Please check code just I edit code, please check with edited code, it will help you

Comment: @DharmeshKheni, you can see the changes, it's not just copy and paste, Here I change segue object globally so when first time perform segue that time we got object with view controller, and we can use that object when we click button which present in container view

Comment: @SapanaRanipa yes that's the solution, declaring it globally

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger, I always use this way, Thanks for your compliment

Comment: how about if vc is not initialized at that time , and you press button ?

Comment: Thank you guys helped me so much but then i press on the button im getting a new error now points.text = String(point) Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: declare your pointsGame = 0, means initialize pointsGame with zero, you got error because it's haven't any value and you use that

Comment: @ShauketSheikh in container view always in first time call this function    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?), so never happen that type of issue

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good Approach to use viewController globally, Best way is to use delegates or notifications.Here is notification example when you Tap on button just post notification after `pointsGame = pointsGame + 1`

```
// Post notification
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "buttonpressed"), object: nil , userInfo: ["points": 20])
```

And in View controller `ViewDidLoad` add observer for notification

```
let name = Notification.Name("buttonpressed")
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshLabel(object:)), name: name, object: nil)


func refreshLabel(_ notification: Notification) {
if let myDict = notification.object as? [String: Any] {
    if let point = myDict["points"] as? Int {
        print(point)
        points.text = String(point)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create One Variable of your container view controller.

```
    var templateVC : GPTemplateVC?
```

Step 2: In Prepare for a segue do this.

```
    if segue.identifier == "embedSegueTemplateVC" {
         templateVC = segue.destination as? GPTemplateVC
    }
```

Then you can access every element from the ContainerVC.

You can also use a delegate for the same.

Just confirm your delegate with your main view controller and call delegate method using delegate object in Container view controller. In your case call it on button click.

Comment: @Ozan Gumustas  declare view controller variable globally.